# How to register MainView to a ComponentEvent that another View fires?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

**How do I register a MainView to an event that another View fires?**

I have tried [ComponentUtil.addListener()](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.20/com/vaadin/flow/component/ComponentUtil.html#addListener-com.vaadin.flow.component.Component-java.lang.Class-com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener-) but it does not work for me. On the other hand I am not even sure if the View that fires the event is even created at the point the MainView can register to the event?

The application flow:

open application -> `MainView` -> reroute if user is not authenticated -> `LoginView` -> `SuccessfulAuthenticationEvent` -> `MainView` reacts on the `SuccessfulAuthenticationEvent` fired in `LoginView`

Event:

```
public class SuccessfulAuthenticationEvent extends ComponentEvent<LoginForm> {
    public SuccessfulAuthenticationEvent(LoginForm source, boolean fromClient) {
        super(source, fromClient);
    }
}
```

MainView:

```
public class MainView extends AppLayout implements ComponentEventListener<SuccessfulAuthenticationEvent> {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onComponentEvent(SuccessfulAuthenticationEvent event) {
        System.out.println("SuccessfulAuthenticationEvent catched");
    }
}
```

LoginView:

```
public class LoginView extends Div {
    ...
    @Override
    public void executeAfterAuthentication() {
        fireEvent(new SuccessfulAuthenticationEvent(loginForm, false));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use different approach, which is more robust.

In the Login view. If the login is successful, save session attribute indicating that user has logged in, e.g.

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("userLoggedIn", true);
```

In your MainLayout implement `BeforeEnterObserver` and override `beforeEnter` method. In the `beforeEnter` method read the session attribute, if it is null forward to login page.

```
@Override
public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    if (VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("userLoggedIn") == null) {
        event.forwardTo(LoginView.class);
    }
}
```

Extra tip. In `beforeEnter` method you can also store current route and in login view if the login is successful reroute to stored route.

```
@Override
public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    if (VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("userLoggedIn") == null) {
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("intendedPath", event.getLocation().getPath());
        ...
    }
}
```

And in login view after succesful login

```
Object intendedPath = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("intendedPath");
UI.getCurrent().navigate(Optional.ofNullable(intendedPath).map(Object::toString).orElse(""));
```